# How to cache data before sending to remote db?

Tags: python, mysql, linux

I have an application which is collecting data from a sensor. This data needs to be stored in a mysql db on a remote host. I want to cache this data somehow before sending it to the remote db to be sure that there is no data lost when the network is temporarily down.

My first idea was to store the data in a local textfile and upload it once a minute to the remote db using mysqls 'load data infile local'. The problem here is that i want to delete the uploaded entries from the textfile after they have been sucsessfully uploaded. But this sometimes corrupts the textfile because the sensor process is still writing to it.

Second idea was using named pipes. But there I have limitited capacity and also had blocking issues...

I'm looking for a solution where the local file normally only contains the measurment data between last upload and now (i.e. data for 1minute ). In case the upload is not working this cache file needs to hold all following (up to the limit of the file system). As soon as the upload is working again, all this stored data needs to be uploaded and removed from the cache file.
Is there an elegant way to achieve this? I'm using Linux, MySql, Python,...

Comment: Have you considered using a rotating log file? You can make it rotate to a new file every minute. If you have a process that tries to send all log files in a directory, you can delete the ones that get successfully sent. Or if you want logical chunks, you can use a regular rotating log handler which will rotate on a particular filesize. This way, you can just check when a file hits like...256KB or something, and then send it. Delete the entire file on success. 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler

Comment: How about cycling through filenames?  You never send a file that is currently being written, so you can delete it after the fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought of using sqlite? This will allow you to use (roughly) the same data layer as with a remote MySQL server, but you can cache locally and then push your inserts when ready.

It uses flat files as a backend, but you don't have to worry about that, and has some command-line tools (similar to MySQL client) for administering the datafiles your app creates.

This link doesn't look to hideous:

http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/

Comment: Thanks for the idea with sqlite - This is working fine for me